# WHATWG: Infra Standard - Clarification (Should be consecutive? Get the indices incorrect definition?)

Tags: list, data-structures, standards, definition

I'm creating a List data structure in PHP based off of the [WHATWG Infra Standard](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#lists) as a programming exercise and am having some issues trying to clarify a couple items.

1. I don't see anywhere that implies that indices in a list must be consecutive. However, it seems to be implied in the [definition of getting the indices of a list](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#list-get-the-indices):

> To get the indices of a list, return the range from 0 to the list’s size, exclusive.

2. In the definition of getting the indices (listed above) it says to return the range from 0 to the list's size, but wouldn't this include one extra index than is actually present? I see the sentence ends with ", exclusive" but I don't know what that means in this context.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operation that would allow for a "sparse" list if that's what you are asking for.
Removing items from a list will make the following items "move" to fill the now empty positions.

And regarding "return the range from 0 to the list’s size, exclusive." "range" is a link to https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#the-exclusive-range, which states

> The range *n* to *m*, exclusive, creates a new [ordered set](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ordered-set) containing all of the integers from *n* up to and including *m − 1* in consecutively increasing order, as long as *m* is greater than *n.* If *m* equals *n*, then it creates an empty [ordered set](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ordered-set).

Don't be afraid of following all the links in the specs if you want to implement it.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks so much. I'll make sure I follow all links in a section I have questions about before looking for help moving forward :)